# Links from Imdb, rottentomatoes and reddit will help website?

Tags: seo

I have created a entertainment website and i have one question about my site. I have good profiles in tv.com (forum), Imdb (forum boards), rottentomatoes (forum boards), voat.co subvoat , reddit.com subreddit (subreddit of 30 page authority), stackexchange.com and forum.blu-ray. If i will submit links in these sites, will this help my site to rank in google first page or not??

Or what i need to rank well in google and how to get backlinks from my own site too. I saw that big sites like stackexchange.com has got more than 20-30 links form own sites.